# Data inserted by wpdb insert is different than data pressnt in database.

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb

I have made this insert query:

```
$insertsuccess = $wpdb->insert( 
    'compservices', 
    array( 
                'orderId'=> $orderID,
        'orderedTime' => $date, 
        'useremail' => $customerEmail,
        'address' => $address , 
        'mobile' => $mobile ,
        'servicecenter' => $servicecentername ,
                'timeslot'=> $timeSlot,
                'preferredlanguage'=> $preferredLanguage,
                'status'=> $orderStatus,
                'completedDate'=> $orderCompletionDate,
                'userissue'=> $userIssue ,
                'userproduct'=> $userProduct
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',
        '%s', 
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s', 
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'

    ) 
);
var_dump( $wpdb->last_query );

//echo $wpdb->insert_id;
//$wpdb->print_error();


if($insertsuccess) {
return true;
} else {
 return false;
}
```

The output of wpdb->last_query is:

```
string(423) "INSERT INTO `compservices` (`orderId`, `orderedTime`, `useremail`, `address`, `mobile`, `servicecenter`, `timeslot`, `preferredlanguage`, `status`, `completedDate`, `userissue`, `userproduct`) VALUES ('GV2016021757', '2016-02-17 23:20', 'abcd@gmail.com', 'jnerjnmejnrerr', '9999999999', 'GVONE', '2016-02-18 - 09 AM to 12 PM', 'ENG', 'Ordered', NULL, '', 'kdnsjknjer')"
```

The actual query is

```
string(423) "INSERT INTO `compservices` (`orderId`, `orderedTime`, `useremail`, `address`, `mobile`, `servicecenter`, `timeslot`, `preferredlanguage`, `status`, `completedDate`, `userissue`, `userproduct`) VALUES ('GV2016021757', '2016-02-17 23:20', 'abcd@gmail.com', 'jnerjnmejnrerr', '9999999999', 'GVONE', '2016-02-18 - 09 AM to 12 PM', 'ENG', 'Ordered', NULL, '<script>alert("hello")</script>', 'kdnsjknjer')"
```

and data inserted is

all data same as well as the script tags are also there:

```
<script>alert(\'hello\')</script>
```

The expectation was wpdb->insert will sanitize the script tags and remove it. It is showing correct in wpdb->last_query. But the data in database has script tags.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: In second last parameter of insert query. I have given input as <script>alert("hello")</script>. In wpdb->last_query, the script tags are replaced but in data base I am seeing script tags are there.

Answer (score 1):

[`wpdb::insert`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/) will only ensure that data is inserted safely (i.e prevents against SQL injection). It will **not** *sanitize* your data (e.g. stripping certain/all HTML), that's down to you.

You can either use [`wp_strip_all_tags`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/), which removes *all* HTML, or a variation of [`wp_kses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/), which is a sophisticated library for removing certain (x)HTML tags & entitites.

> The output of wpdb->last_query is:

You've been tricked! The reason you don't *see* `<script>alert(\'hello\')</script>` is because it's being parsed by the browser when you output it - if you escape your debug output you'll see the two are the same:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $wpdb->last_query ) ?>
```

Comment: So to secure from XSS attacks, we need to santize and validate data from our side and wordpress will take care of SQL injection attacks. Right?

Comment: Correct - WordPress has all the tools, but it's up to you to use them as you see fit.